# Reset drop-downs

Tags: google-sheets

I have created several drop-down menus, what I would like to know is, is it possible and if so how do I create a script so that once a user has finished with the sheet they press a button or it self resets itself to the top value or better blank as per the black drop-downs in the screenshot?

I have attached a simple screenshot of the tabs in question, if you need more info please ask.

[image: screenshot of drop-down cells]

Answer (score 2):

You want a user to be able to clear a series of dropdown cells by clicking a button.

An excellent answer is found in [Google Support](https://support.google.com/docs/forum/AAAABuH1jm0wOgLAug3DbY) from Dec 2016. Since this is an external source, I have adapted and expanded it here. Props to "Munkey (David)" who supplied the original answer.

The script to clear/reset the dropdown value is very simple and uses the method`.clearContent()`. When the dropdown cells are cleared, the values for "Position score" and "Position Explanation" (which, in my test data, are based on `VLOOKUP` formula) become blank by virtue of using `IFERROR` in conjunction with the `VLOOKUP`.

However... you have several ranges to reset and there are options for describing those ranges.

1 - refer to specified range (such as "B5:F5"). This will work well, but in the event that you insert a row, expand the spreadsheet, etc, then the script would need to be edited.

2 - refer to a named range (such as "DropdownSet1"). A named range will be updated as rows are added or deleted, and this avoids editing of the script.

This solution doesn't offer a button option; instead the trigger to clear the dropdowns is included in a custom menu. You should delete whichever option you don't wish to use.

---

```
// Reference: https://support.google.com/docs/forum/AAAABuH1jm0wOgLAug3DbY
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('Clear Dropdowns')
      .addItem('Clear by Range name', 'clearDropdownRangesByName')
      .addItem('Clear by Cell reference', 'clearDropdownRangesByCell')
      .addToUi();
}

function clearDropdownRangesByName() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetname = "Sheet1";
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);

  var dropdownNames = ["DropdownSet1","DropdownSet2","DropdownSet3"];

  for (var i=0;i<dropdownNames.length;i++){
    sheet.getRange(dropdownNames[i]).clearContent();
  }  
}

function clearDropdownRangesByCell() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetname = "Sheet1";
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);

  var dropdownRanges = ["B5:F5","B11:F11","B17:F17"];

  for (var i=0;i<dropdownRanges.length;i++){
    sheet.getRange(dropdownRanges[i]).clearContent();
  }  
}
```

---

**Before**

[image: Before]

---

**After**

[image: After screenshot]

---

Comment: Hi Tedinoz Thanks for the response, I have had a go but I don't see the results so I expect I have messed up. You will have to excuse me as I self teach myself and this is my first look into scripts! If I send a link to my spreadsheet here would you be able to take a look for me and adjust the script as needed? Thanks –

Comment: Sure thing. You should be aware that sharing your spreadsheet will unavoidably expose your email address.

Comment: Thanks - I have set everything but the drop downs to protected so if you need access just let me know, I have no issue with email being exposed.   https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gdfHZX2qjKGn-SUdOMp8KFZ_AAxnbPbj9_1DW0Bbzi0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Morning Tedinoz. Have you had a chance to take a look at this yet? if not it's fine, I only ask because I am leaving it alone until I know the script is working so not to interfere at the wrong time :).

Comment: You have protected ranges in that sheet - that's why the script isn't working.

Comment: The ranges that are needed for the script are not protected, do I need to un-protect the whole spreadsheet?

Comment: I tried it on a duplicate of the sheet, and the dropdown ranges were cleared.

Comment: Ok, If you have checked my sheet and my script I don't know what it's not clearing for me but thanks for the help and advice.