# How to make the specific dropdown list reset to the specific choice daily?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

Here is the basic layout of what I need.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1t2FlKs3TTVsGp3co6SkFlfCb3EPDWv-i6g9su4o_flQ/edit#gid=1850242391

It's a daily check-in document that people come to update their information daily and I want the check-in status to reset to "Uncheck" everyday so I can see who isn't update their information yet on the current date.

I couldn't find the proper script that could solve this solution for me as I have very little knowledge about the coding part.
Please, I need anyone help with this as I tried for days but it isn't work for me.
Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Have you considered [creating a form](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6281888) instead of sharing a spreadsheet for data input? Also see [How do I ask a good question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi, welcome to WebApps. Your dropdowns are not working at all. You need to enter the validation choices "Uncheck" and "Updated" into cells A4 and A5 of the sheet called "Drop Down List".

Comment: The suggestion by @doubleunary to use a form is a good idea. It means your users don't have access to your spreadsheet and data analysis is as easy as entering the date to be checked. This answer [How to make a query with Google Spreadsheet, that checks for a date](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/30517/196152) provides the query to analyse the form results. The only down-side would be if you were (also?) interested in the artists that were NOT in on a given day - but that could be easily solved too.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this.

**1-Write a script**

Write a script that will update the status column once a day.

The WebApps question [Reset drop-downs](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/140886/196152) contains a solution/precedent, but you said *I have very little knowledge about the coding part*  so I don't see how you could develop this script quickly.

To learn scripting, you might start to the [Overview](https://www.google.com/script/start/), [Guide to Automating Tasks with Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/samples), the [Extending Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets) page, [Triggers and Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers?hl=en) and the [Mozilla Javascript Tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)

**2) Paste the new value**

This is VERY easy and takes almost no time at all.

- chose a cell in Column A that displays "Uncheck"
- copy the value of that cell
- select the range in Column A from Cell A2 to the bottom of the Column (or at least to the bottom of the Data validation cells)
- paste "Uncheck" into every Data Validation cell.